# preposition till or for

Tags: prepositions

What preposition do we use for duration? **till** or **for**? e.g.

> They will live in there **for** hundreds of years.

OR

> They will live in there **till** hundreds of years.

Comment: The meanings are different. **For** a period of time, or **till** (until) a particular date or happening.

Comment: Since *until* mentions a specific time, you need some other phrase to indicate duration. The second example could be "They will live in there *until* hundreds of years *have passed*."

Answer (score 3):

**till** uses a definite time to process the termination ([Preposition, 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/till#Preposition)), e.g.

> they lived there till 1890.

**for** describes a duration ([Preposition, 5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Preposition)), e.g.

> they lived there for a hundred years

Comment: **Till** is also used for actions/processes in time. **Till** the oven was hot. **Till** he passed away. **Till** they had crossed the sea.

Comment: @RonaldSole; your examples all use the idea of an event precipitating the end of a process, rather than a pre-defined duration (in theory anyway! - an oven set to 180C takes x minutes to get there I suppose)

Comment: like repeat...until versus a 'for' loop in [computer control structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops) @RonaldSole

Comment: Agreed. My examples were intended only to complement your answer.